# Using union inside a foreach loop for linq to sql

Tags: linq

In the below code I expect to retrn n rows but it always returns zero rows as my initial set has zero records. Ideally it should be doing a UNION ALL and returning me records for all of the integers in the integer list clearanceTotals{6,7,8,9,17}
Any idea how to go about it?

```
    var tbl = (from a in db.Applicants
    where a.Id == null
    select new { a.Id, a.Firstname, a.Lastname });
    int thisTag;
    foreach (int c in clearanceTotals)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 6:
                thisTag = 38;
                break;
            case 8:
                thisTag = 39;
                break;
            case 17:
                thisTag = 39;
                break;
            case 7:
                thisTag = 42;
                break;
            case 9:
                thisTag = 44;
                break;
        }
        tbl = (from a in db.Applicants
               join ad in db.ApplicantDeployments on a.Id equals ad.ApplicantId
               join aa in db.ApplicantAttachments on a.Id equals aa.ApplicantId
               where a.Nationality == 15 && a.DoNotUse == false && a.ClearanceStatus == c
               && aa.Tag == thisTag
               select new { a.Id, a.Firstname, a.Lastname }).Union(tbl);
    }
```

Comment: Try adding a `.ToList()` so the `.Union` doesn't attempt to process on the database side.

Comment: Don't add ToList because you probably want to execute the union in the database!

Comment: I cant do ToList(), although doing so does return all the IDs that I need and then I can run another query to get other column associated with that ID. But is there another way.

Comment: Just to make sure the data in your joined tables is not causing the problem, what effect does it have if you replaced your query with this: `from a in db.Applicants where a.ClearanceStatus == c select new { a.Id, a.Firstname, a.Lastname }.Union(tbl);` ?

Comment: But I really need the joins..otherwise the resultant set is not what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i got this to work but its additional code plus additional variables

```
var temp = (from a in db.Applicants 
where a.Id == null 
select a.Id).ToList(); 

int thisTag; 
foreach (int c in clearanceTotals) 
{ 
    switch (c) 
    { 
        case 6: 
            thisTag = 38; 
            break; 
        case 8: 
            thisTag = 39; 
            break; 
        case 17: 
            thisTag = 39; 
            break; 
        case 7: 
            thisTag = 42; 
            break; 
        case 9: 
            thisTag = 44; 
            break; 
    }
    temp = temp.Union(from a in db.Applicants 
           join ad in db.ApplicantDeployments on a.Id equals ad.ApplicantId 
           join aa in db.ApplicantAttachments on a.Id equals aa.ApplicantId 
           where a.Nationality == 15 && a.DoNotUse == false && a.ClearanceStatus == c 
           && aa.Tag == thisTag 
           select a.Id).ToList(); 
}
var tbl = (from a in db.Applicants
                      join ad in db.ApplicantDeployments on a.Id equals ad.ApplicantId
                      where temp.Contains(a.Id) 
                      select new { a.Id, a.Firstname, a.Lastname }).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're capturing the loop variable (`c`) in the query, so when the query is executed, it uses only the latest value of c. Try copying c to a variable inside the loop:

```
foreach (int c in clearanceTotals)
{
    int c2 = c;
    ...

        ...
        where a.Nationality == 15 && a.DoNotUse == false && a.ClearanceStatus == c2
        ...
```

Comment: No, this doesn't help either...as soon as it moves to the next value of c the tbl variable goes to zero records.

Comment: Trying a similar thing, I understand your explanation but the local variable fix doesn't change anything for me either.